# What's the physical link between Volts and Amperes?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, si-units

I have a question about the link between volts and amperes.

I understand the math theory behind it.

V = W /A

so if i double V i got

2V = 2 (W / A) = 2W / A

So if i raise the voltage i raise the power and not the flow.

Electricity is always explained using the water metaphor, V being the pressure, and A being the flow of water.

But with water, if i raise pressure without touching the tube, the flow also raises. So why not with electrons ?

Is it the end of the metaphor ?

My question is this:

Which physical phenomenon makes that when i raise V i do not raise A (an electron-related answer would be much appreciated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> V = W /A

That relationship describes the power delivered to a two-terminal device. It is more traditionally written with the symbols $I$ for current in Amperes, and $W$ for power in Watts.

$P=IV$

> so if i double V i got 2V = 2 (W / A) = 2W / A

So far, so good.  If the voltage across some device in a circuit is $V$ and the current through it is $I$, then we can conclude that the power dissipated in the device is $P_1=IV$

Meanwhile if the voltage across a *second* device is $2V$ and the current through the second device is $I$, then we can compute the power dissipated in the second device as $P_2=I2V=2P_1$.

> So if i raise the voltage i raise the power and not the flow.

This is where you are losing track of what the formula means. Your formula does not say anything about the relationship between $V$ and $I$ in any given device. It tells how to calculate $P$ if you know $V$ and $I$, but it does *not* tell you how $I$ or $P$ will *change* in any given circuit if you turn a dial and change $V$.

Electrical engineers call the relationship between $V$ and $I$ for a given, two-terminal device its *[I-V Characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic)*, or "curent-voltage characteristic."  It frequently looks like $I=f(V)$ where $f$ is a [monotonically increasing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

In the special case where the device is a *[resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor)* or a *[conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conductor)*, then $f$ is a linear function that passes through the origin: $I=VR$, where $R$ is an intrinsic property of the device known as its *[resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance)*. This special form of I-V characteristic function is known as *[Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)*.

If you substitute Ohm's law into $P=IV$, you get:

$P=IV=(\frac{V}{R})V=\frac{V^2}{R}$

That's the formula that tells you what will happen to the power when you dial-up the voltage on a fixed resistor:  The power will increase as the square of the voltage.

Comment: I think i'm starting to grasp this. Thanks a lot. I have an other question, What is "P" ? (physically)

Comment: The $P$ stands for "Power." which is measured in Watts.  Power can be understood as the rate of change of Energy.  If You deliver a constant $P$ Watts of power to some device, then at the end of $T$ seconds, you will have delivered $P\times{}T$ Joules of energy. It's the same power and energy that are related by other formulas to force and distance and time in mechanical systems. I wish I could tell you more, but that's about as deep as my understanding goes.

Comment: I think i understand now, Thanks. And this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity?fbclid=IwAR0Gr-GjwQOPxmMPM5YiPsu7VkA6_lZ2zmxIlWrdnqey4sRBoxFgNupDyF4 helped in understanding how a change in current affects the electrons

Answer (score 0):

"Which physical phenomenon makes that when i raise V i do not raise A [?]"

For every simple conductor that I can think of, when you raise the potential difference, *V*, across it you do increase the current, *I*, though it – as with pressure difference and flow rate in the water analogy.

The pd, *V*, divided by the length of the conductor tells you the force per unit charge acting on charges in the conductor. So doubling the pd doubles the force that acts on each 'free' electron in the conductor. This increases the free electrons' 'drift velocity' along the conductor (superimposed on their large thermal velocities). The drift velocity is limited by the collisions between the free electrons and the positive ions stationary in the conductor. But doubling *V* will increase the drift velocity and hence the *I*. For some conductors (e.g. metals at constant temperature), doubling *V* will double *I*, that is Ohm's law is obeyed.

Warning: this explanation is simplified.